# Yesterday interview question i tried a lot i did not get it can any one help me with this Need to update table 1 based on table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table1

```
 medicineid    bmi

 1             null  
 2              null     
 3              null          
 4              null         
 5              null
```

Table2

```
 medicineid    bmi

 3              null              
 5              null
```

----OUTPUT----

```
 medicineid    bmi 



 1              null  
 2              null     
 3              no         
 4              null         
 5              no
```

Comment: Could use an outer join, or a union/group by, or ...

Comment: Would be nice if you accept answer helped you the most.

Answer (score 1):

You can do inner join with update on these tables like below, I assume if record exists in table2 then we want to update table1 bmi to 'no'

```
Update t1
set bmi = 'no'
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.medicineid = t2.medicineid
```

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you are asking, do you want to alter the content of table1 ?
A simple update statement can do that

```
update table1
set    bmi = 'no'
where  medicineid in (select medicineid from table2)
```

Comment: It doesn't matter in this simple example, but am I correct to say we should avoid sub-selects as they are expensive?

Comment: @PawelCz Well that depends, in this simple example the optimizer will be able to use about the same execution plan. In more complex queries it might make a difference but it is not so that sub-selects are always slower

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE ##Table1  (medicineid INT, bmi VARCHAR(50)) 
CREATE TABLE ##Table2  (medicineid INT, bmi VARCHAR(50))  
INSERT INTO ##Table1 VALUES
(1, null),(2, null),(3, null),(4, null),(5, null)
INSERT INTO ##Table2 VALUES
(3, null),(5, null);


UPDATE  ##Table1
SET ##Table1.bmi = 'no'
FROM ##Table1 SI
INNER JOIN ##Table2 RAN
ON   SI.medicineid = RAN.medicineid;
----------------------------------------------

-- Answer
SELECT
A.medicineid,
A.bmi
FROM ##Table1 A
LEFT JOIN ##Table2 B
ON A.medicineid=B.medicineid
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `EXISTS` with `UPDATE` statement :

```
UPDATE t1
    SET t1.bmi = 'no'
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t2 WHERE t2.medicineid = t.medicineid);
```